# Style QToolButton set with QWidgetAction

Tags: pyside6

I'm trying to style a QWidgetAction in a QToolBar and following is the minimal reproducible code:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]


class extmenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(extmenu, self).__init__()

    def load(self):
        lay = QHBoxLayout()
        for i in li:
            b = QPushButton()
            b.setText(str(i))
            lay.addWidget(b)
        self.setLayout(lay)


class rtem(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(rtem, self).__init__()

        self.tb = QToolBar()

        self.extmen = extmenu()
        self.extmen.load()

        self.men = QMenu()

        self.wid = QWidgetAction(self.tb)
        self.wid.setText("wid")
        self.wid.setObjectName("wid")

        self.wid.setDefaultWidget(self.extmen)
        self.men.addAction(self.wid)
        self.wid.setMenu(self.men)

        self.act = QAction("act")
        self.act.setObjectName("act")

        self.tb.addAction(self.act)
        self.tb.addAction(self.wid)

        self.tb.setStyleSheet("QToolButton#wid{background: red;}")

        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.tb)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)
```

The setStyleSheet does not have any effect on neither "act" or "wid".

```
        self.tb.setStyleSheet("QToolButton{background: red;}")
        self.tb.setStyleSheet("QToolButton:checked{background: green;}")
```

The code above works.

Styling self.but obviously does not work.

How do I style the QWidgetAction? And why does stylesheet has no effect on individual QToolButtons?

Doing something like:

```
        self.tb.children()[5].setStyleSheet("background: red;")
```

works but not sure this is the way to do it.

Comment: The last part of your question is confusing: first you write "The code above works" (which I suppose is referred to the two separate lines), then you ask "why does stylesheet has no effect on individual QToolButtons?". What do you mean? Besides: 1. You use the `QToolButton` selector, but you're adding QPushButtons to the QWidgetAction; 2. You're using the object name selector, but you're setting the name of the *action*, not of the button, which is useless because actions are ***not*** widgets (so, they're not styled) and the object name should refer to the styled object, it's not "inherited".

Comment: please answer my question and try to be more clear.

Comment: @musicamante The button was the parent of the widget and now I've removed the button and set the toolbar as parent of qwidget action. I can style the intended "qtoolbutton" if I do it by accessing via children list of toolbar.

Comment: Sorry but you've still not answered what I asked in my first comment. Also, your code is quite confusing. Why are you creating a QWidgetAction, then created a menu to which you added that action, and then you're also adding that action to the toolbar. That doesn't make any sense. What do you want to style? The buttons of `extmenu`, or the button used for its QWidgetAction? Note that if you want a custom menu shown for a toolbar action, you don't need to add the QWidgetAction to the toolbar, but an action that shows a menu *containing* that QWidgetAction.